# Checking unique value constraint in database from a user registration

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

I need to check the availability with the username, it means, each username must be unique and I need to show a message "This username already is in use" when already exists an identical username. It can be automatic (Generate a query and then show a message) or create a button to verify the availability and then it show a message. I don't have a clear idea about this simple procedure. What I need to do in this case?
The source code is like so:

**Person class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firtsname")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name="username", unique=true)
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**PersonDao>>PersonDaoImpl**

```
@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void createPerson(Person person) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(person);

}

@Override
public Person updatePerson(int id) {
    return (Person) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, id);

}

@Override
public void deletePerson(int id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Person WHERE id="+id).executeUpdate();

}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Person> listAllPersons() {
    return (List<Person>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class).list();

}

}
```

**Registration form (registration.jsp):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" action="/userform/saveUser.html">
    <p>
        <form:input type="hidden" readonly="true" path="id" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="first_name" >First name:</form:label>
        <form:input path="first_name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="last_name">Last name:</form:label>
        <form:input path="last_name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="user_name">Username:</form:label>
        <form:input path="user_name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
        <form:input path="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" value="Save">Save</button> 
    </p>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just try the insert and handle the failure. Any other approach is vulnerable to timing-window problems.

Comment: also the other solution contains one select and one insert, consider that select usually considers to be a heavy operation, this way you save on select

Comment: @EJP Your answer sounds good. May you explain it with source code? From my user registrarion form (registrarion.jsp)... How can I check if already exists a username with the same name in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = "user_key"
```

if it returns selected username then you know you already got it. And once you know it, your layout-function can show message "this username is taken". It also would be nice if you make the `id` cell `unique` in your database. Thats all.

PS: If your id cell is `unique` then your can make `INSERT` and catch exception. Thats second solution.